# Consequences of no constructor in java OOP

Tags: java, oop, constructor

my question is pretty much in the title. I know that I will be given a default constructor if none is explicitly defined, but if there were no constructors in my class at all, what could I not do? My lecturer has been hounding me for days and no matter how many articles I read I just can't find the answer to this.It is a fundamental of Java that is affected if you do not have any constructor whatsoever.

I apologise for maybe a trivial question but I'm getting desperate

Comment: I've never really thought about it, but if you had no constructor at all, I don't see how you could code in the OOP structure.

Comment: You cannot create an object, and hence cannot access the non-static content without a constructor.

Comment: Define "no constructor". Do you mean no _accessible_ constructor?

Comment: @fge Literally, no constructor

Comment: If you want to see that yourself, then try making a private default constructor. `class ABC { private ABC() {}}`. Here, you cannot call the constructor, which is almost the same as not having a constructor.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't understand my question. You said it yourself, if no constructor is defined in the code of a class, a default one is created for you. So, again, define what you mean exactly.

Comment: No constuctor means class will have default constructor that will run default block. You can override this behaviour by writing `private` constructor that would prevent create a instance of class outside of it.

Comment: @fge OP knows that. He's asking what would be the consequences of not explicitly defining a constructor, *and* if Java never gave you a default constructor. You literally didn't have one.

Comment: There is a design patterns where we explicitly say we dont want a constructor by making it `private` this is called `singleton`. It's useful when you want to make sure that only one instance is created fx in parallel programming.

Comment: @RayOldProf singleton pattern **has** a constructor. That is not what the question is asking. It specifically says no constructor at all

Comment: @Hackerdarshi That is actually the answer which makes sense to me and I feel answers the question. We wouldnt be able to create the objects

Comment: @duldi it depend´s, as @RayOldProf alredy mentioned, the design pattern you are desribing is basicly the `singleton`, if you hide the default constructor aswell. The standard procedure of this pattern would be to hold a variable of the class itself inside the class. This variable would be initiazed by a method like `getInstance`, which would basicly initialize the variable, if it wasn´t initialized yet, and return the variable. So the pattern doesn´t let you explicity create an instance of the class, but implicity you retrieve it due something like the `getInstance` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there were no constructors in my class at all, what could I not do

1. You cannot initialize your object's member variables  using constructor parameters. In order to do that, you would need to use setX methods for nonpublic (protected, private) variables, or use dot notation if they are public.
2. As a side effect of 1, you cannot have uninitialized final member variables

Having no constructor does not prevent you from instantiating the object as the default constructor will be made. You cannot just "remove" the default constructor to literally have no constructor.

Comment: in original question: ...I know that **I will be given a default constructor** if none is explicitly defined, **but** if there were **no constructors** in my class at all...

Comment: @ErnestSadykov Considering OP is being asked this by a teacher, I don't think the question is asking about absolutely no constructors, e.g. removing the default, because that completely breaks OOP

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **No-constructor in concrete types** and **Java** are two concepts that cannot live next to each other:

No concrete type in Java exists without constructor. That is, the Java compiler won't let you define a class without a constructor (implicit or otherwise).

No object that is created is created without a constructor (though there are a myriad ways of invoking constructors).

**So: What would happen if you had no constructor at all? You wouldn't have any runnable Java code.**

Comment: "_So: What would happen if you had no constructor at all? You wouldn't have any runnable Java code._". No, that's not true. We can have main methods, which **is** runnable code.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi That's because the constructor is implicitly created for the class containing the main method, as already explained

Comment: Yes, but the question and the answer are about a class with no constructor (context of the question). And main methods live in classes with at least one constructor (usually the default one), even though no instances of the class are needed to run main()..

Comment: @cricket_007 But it is not used.

Comment: That's the point of my answer. Java won't allow you to add a class without constructor, it gives you one by default and doesn't give you means of 'not having a constructor'. That's why it's impossible as long as Java is the language.

Comment: A 'singleton' is an "instance" of a class (ie, it's an object resulting from a constructor invocation). The "main" method is static (meaning that it's executed without an instance of the class). Please check your concepts. In either case, a constructor will be present (for the singleton, it's obvious, an object was created, therefore a constructor is present. In the case of the main (static) method, the class having it cannot not have a constructor, explicit or not)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few situations in which you don't need to create an explicit constructor. For example, you can instantiate all default values in the declaration of members and then use setters for creating values.

```
class SoccerTeam {
    private final List<Person> members = new ArrayList<>();
    private double budget = 0.0;

    public void setBudget(double budget) {
        this.budget = budget;
    }

    public void addMember(Person member) {
        members.add(member);
        budget -= member.getSalary();
    }

    public boolean isBroke() {
        return budget < 0;
    }
}
```

this could be used as you would expect:

```
SoccerTeam acMilan = new SoccerTeam();
acMilan.setBudget(1000000);
acMilan.addMember(messi);
assertTrue(acMilan.isBroke());
```

That's a perfectly acceptable and usable class with no constructor defined.

To answer your lecturer's question, one of the key limitations is that it makes it difficult to define [immutable objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html). These are objects that are given state when they are constructed and then never change. There are lots of advantages to using immutable objects whenever possible (particular when your code relies on concurrency) but they generally rely on setting `final` instance variables using values passed into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he's referring to the fact that without a constructor, the JVM doesn't know that it has to reserve memory for the object?

Answer (score 0):

Without a constructor, you cannot create new instance of a class. However, all Java classes have a constructor. If you don't write a constructor yourself, the compiler generates a default constructor for you. So the question of your instructor is comparable to: what would happen if the earth were flat? The answer is: I don't care, it is not so.

However, you can specify a constructor which is not visible, for example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since the class has a constructor, the compiler will not generate one, and thus, the only constructor of the class is not visible to any other class. If the class does not provide any static methods which create instances of the class, no instances of the class can be created, and thus only the static methods and variables of the class can be used. In fact, this is a standard pattern to prevent anyone from instantiating a class (for example if the class only provides a set of static utility methods).